# SwiftUI Navigation Bar Title doesn't appear

Tags: swiftui

I'm not sure if anything changed in Beta 3, however, when trying to add the NavigationBarTitle modifier to NavigationView, it does not show the text for the title? Any ideas?

```
NavigationView {
         List(0 ..< 20) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("1")) {
                Text("Navigate 1")
            }
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Update")).navigationBarHidden(false)
}
```

The list shows but no title for the list in the NavigationView

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're setting `.navigationBarTitle` and `.navigationBarHidden` on `NavigationView` when they should be modifiers on `List` instead:

```swift
NavigationView {
    List(0..<20) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("1")) {
            Text("Navigate 1")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Update")
    .navigationBarHidden(false)
}
```

You can also just remove `.navigationBarHidden(false)` (unless you're setting it to `true` in a previous view or something).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine and the `navigationBarTitle` is not outdated. It must be placed above (inside the Navigation View). Yes, it is sometimes confusing, it is necessary to remember this.

To the place where you currently have it `.navigationBarTitle(Text ("Update")).navigationBarHidden(false)` you need to set the modifier `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle ())`, which means that you should always show the first screen regardless of the screen size.

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                 List(0 ..< 20) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("1")) {
                        Text("Navigate 1")
                    }
                }
                 .navigationBarTitle(Text("Update"), displayMode: .automatic).navigationBarHidden(false)
            }
        // that means only show one view at a time no matter what device I'm working
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
```